# Which security packages exists for Smalltalk?

Tags: security, acl, smalltalk

I'm looking for a package in any Smalltalk dialect that provides me to provide several security features for my system. For example: To manage failed logins, brute force attacks, user/password organization, ACL's, check points, etc. It could be based in roles or capabilities. If you could share your experience with the library it will be even better to gain some additional insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Application Security package](http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/~hernan/ApplicationSecurity) in [Pharo](http://pharo.org/) implements the [CheckPoint security pattern](http://80738163270632.blogspot.com.ar/2014/10/application-security-2-checkpoint.html), uses the [Nacl cryptographic library](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/) (SHA-512 through the [libsodium binding](http://www.eighty-twenty.org/index.cgi/tech/smalltalk/nacl-for-squeak-and-pharo-20130601.html)), an [user model](http://80738163270632.blogspot.com.ar/2014/03/application-security-presentation.html) supporting groups and candidates, network security utilities like network class based filtering, and [password rules](http://80738163270632.blogspot.com.ar/2015/02/application-security-3-setting-your.html) as recommended by the FIPS.

Sample code is provided in SUnit tests and linked blog posts.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a library.

The [Pier](http://www.piercms.com/) content management system has a sophisticated security system, modelling users, groups and permissions. This is used in most Pier sites to have a fine-grained access control over parts of the site (e.g. visitors that see only the public parts, editors that can edit the public parts and see some internal things, admins that have access to everything).

Also there used to be a pluggable security system based on ACL for Pier. It is not maintained anymore, but you might leverage code from there.

Comment: So, it is possible to load the built-in security system without having to install Pier? Otherwise would you mind to provide a link to review the ACL pluggable system for Pier?

Answer (score 1):

[Aida](http://www.aidaweb.si) web framework has built-in security framework with users/groups management, access rights, encrypted/nonencrypted views, encrypted passwords, login/failed login management, XSS attacks, etc. [Scribo](http://www.aidaweb.si/scribo) CMS has then ACLs implementented on top of above.

Comment: Thanks, from your answer it seems to have the same issues as the Pier security system. It is loadable out of the Aida box?

Comment: No, but with a little effort I think it could be made standalone.